# How to use console.log to get a specific value of an object in nested objects

Tags: arrays, console.log, nested-object

```
const businessInfo = {
  firstName: "Fred",
  lastName: "Stone",
  company: {
    name: "Software Solutions",
    jobTitle: "Chief Technology Officer",
  },
  employee: [
    {
      firstName: "Pete",
      lastName: "Perkins",
      department: {
        name: "Front End",
        jobTitle: "Junior Developer",
      },
    },
    {
      firstName: "Jack",
      lastName: "Steel",
      department: {
        name: "Back End",
        jobTitle: "Senior Developer",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

With **console.log**, I want to access **name: "Front End", jobTitle: "Junior Developer"** within **department** for **Pete**. I figure I need at least ***console.log(businessInfo.employee)*** but I am stuck beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access name and jobTitle property like this

```
console.log(businessInfo.employee.department.name);
console.log(businessInfo.employee.department.jobTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the following solutions work:

```
  console.log(businessInfo.employee[0].department);
  console.log(businessInfo['employee'][0]['department']);
  console.log(businessInfo["employee"][0]["department"]);
```